# Encoded UTF-8 Code and unreadable characters in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8

I have a problem in eclipse, i imported a project , maybe i changed the encoding to UTF-8 then i reset it back to default; but in the whole code where there is special characters like accents , they turned into unreadable symbols (as the screenshot show). is there any ways to reformat the code and get back the original code. Know that when i write myself accented letters it's shown as normal without problems

[image]

Comment: Is it just those lines?  You might find it easier to just globally search and replace `Soci�t�s` with `Sociétés`.

Comment: No it's in the whole project,  and its mixed between ' and éèêâà not juste those lines or alike.